# Rewriting domain (or IP address) within an HTML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using jQuery to `load()` a third-party HTML file for which I inject it into a DIV of our current HTML page.

```
$("#external-page").load(URL, function() {
   injectDataInPage();
   doOtherStuffInPage();
});
```

This works very well. The major problem is that they have added a lot of code in their HTML (ie: buttons which issue server requests and resources loaded from another server, etc).

If they have used paths only for their requests then it would be ok but unfortunately, they specify the domain and sometimes an IP address.

I would like to replace ALL of the hard-coded domain and IP addresses to point to my own server.

So for example, these:

```
<a href='http://external.com/some/path/of/service'>Click here</a>

<img src='http://10.2.3.4/some/path/to/image.png'>
```

Would be remapped to:

```
<a href='http://my.domain.com/some/path/of/service'>Click here</a>

<img src='http://my.domain.com/some/path/to/image.png'>
```

I know you can probably do it with IIS plugins or a Node.js or something but is it possible to actually do it on the client with jQuery? Either once the page has been added to the DOM or possibly before injecting it to the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Insert it after loading done.

```
$('a[href]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace("http://external.com", "http://my.domain.com");
});

$('img[src]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("http://10.2.3.4", "http://my.domain.com");
});
```

You can prepend `'a[href]'` with some div selector: `'.mydiv a[href]'` to prevent watching all the elements.

Comment: Or just replace it in your html before injecting into DOM: `returnedHtml.replace("from", "to")`. Why do you think you need node.js for this?

Comment: I had tried the `html.replace("from", "to")` but that messed up absolutely everything. I will revisit this idea and see why it had not worked. Thanks!

Comment: The only reason I'm considering Node.js for this is simply because I know it can be done. But additionally, there are other more complex API's the third-party has provided which makes absolutely no sense. With Node.js it allows me to have more control and create an "adaptor" for those API's. But if I could avoid Node.js altogether it would be better.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, I will try a few things and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find something like URI.js useful. For instance, you could use a replace function with their [resource()](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-resource) function to make all the URLs relative.

For example:

```
$("#external-page").load(URL, function() {
    injectDataInPage();

    $("#external-page img").each(function(i, img){
        var src = $(img).attr('src');
        $(img).attr('src', new URI(src).resource());
    }); 

    $("#external-page a:link").each(function(i, link){
        var href = $(link).attr('href');
        $(link).attr('href', new URI(href).resource());
    }); 

    doOtherStuffInPage();
});
```

Granted, this is untested, but the idea should be obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, I will try a few things and see how it works out.